# "ImportError: No module named tensorflow"; However, I can import time, math, and numpy

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to do the following:

```
import time
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
import math
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
```

I can import time, math, and numpy without any issues, however I get the following error when trying to import tensorflow:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/[user]/Desktop/SABR/sabr.py", line 2, in <module>
     import tensorflow as tf
ImportError: No module named tensorflow
```

I followed the exact steps listed in https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

"pip3 list" returns:

```
Package              Version
-------------------- -------
absl-py              0.7.0  
astor                0.7.1  
gast                 0.2.2  
grpcio               1.19.0 
h5py                 2.9.0  
Keras-Applications   1.0.7  
Keras-Preprocessing  1.0.9  
Markdown             3.0.1  
mock                 2.0.0  
numpy                1.16.2 
pandas               0.24.1 
pbr                  5.1.3  
pip                  19.0.3 
protobuf             3.7.0  
python-dateutil      2.8.0  
pytz                 2018.9 
setuptools           40.8.0 
six                  1.12.0 
tensorboard          1.13.1 
tensorflow           1.13.1 
tensorflow-estimator 1.13.0 
termcolor            1.1.0  
Werkzeug             0.14.1 
wheel                0.33.1
```

One thing I did notice, however, is that when I do

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

I get the following, which seem to be building python 2.7 rather than 3.6 (as intended)

```
['/Users/[user]/Desktop', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/UNKNOWN-16.4.3-py2.7.egg', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC']
```

How do get tensorflow to use python 3.6 rather than 2.7? Is that the issue?

For reference, I'm using:  
 - macOS Mojave Version 10.14.3  
 - Atom IDE  
 - Python 3.6  
 - tensorflow 1.13.1

Comment: Are you using the `virtualenv`? If yes, make sure it is activated?

Comment: I would highly recommend using a virtual environment to ensure this does not happen. Learning to use virtualenv is a better use of your time than debugging this. Pipenv is a high level abstraction of virtualenv that makes it work like a breeze. See: https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: or just simply run your script using `python3` instead of just `python`

Comment: @PS1212 I'm using virtualenv and it's activated

Comment: @Vaibhavgusain could you elaborate? I created a new virtual environment with "virtualenv --system-site-packages -p python3 ./venv". Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: @processingboi yes and i guess you need to make sure that you installed your tensorflow inside that virtual env

Comment: You ran the python binary (which is most likely python 2.7), you need to run the python3 binary, as you used pip3 to install tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out Intel tensorflow wheel in a conda environment. Please follow the below steps.

1. Create a conda environment

   conda create -n env_name -c intel python=3.6 pip numpy
2. Activate the same

   source activate env_name
3. Install tensorflow :

   pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/intel-optimized-tensorflow/tensorflow-1.11.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl

For new version of tensorflow wheel, you can refer: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-optimization-for-tensorflow-installation-guide